# Parameter query doesn't return the value of an auto number control

Tags: ms-access

I have a form linked to a table. The form has 4 text boxes: one linked to the autonumber field, and the other three to text fields.

There is also a subform, from which I wish to launch a query (via button and macro) combining results from the subform and a control on the main form. When I specify any of the three text-based controls in a parameter query, this works fine, but asking for the value of the first (autonumber) control results in a symbol being displayed instead of a value.

I wasn't sure what specific information/images would be helpful. Please ask for specific information if you feel it would help.

Comment: What symbol is being displayed? Maybe the width of the control is not as wide as the number of characters in the record.

Comment: Just a minus sign. The numbers in the offending field are currently single digits, and the width is more than sufficiant. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: When you say that you "specify the controls in a parameter query", what do you mean? Are you passing the value of the field to a parameter query and returning the results? As far as information, it might help to have a screenshot of the form and the code you are using to combine the results.

Comment: @Neil Yes, the contents of the text box is returned as one field in a query. I'll post screen shots when I can get at the file - it's at work and I'm not. Sorry.

Comment: I can't directly post images without 10 rep, so here are links to the images: [Form](http://owl-internet.co.uk/images/springs/form.jpg), [Table](http://owl-internet.co.uk/images/springs/table_design.jpg), [Query Design](http://owl-internet.co.uk/images/springs/query_design.jpg),[Query Result](http://owl-internet.co.uk/images/springs/query_result.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've been given the answer elsewhere. I had to implicitly convert the results of the batch field into an int.
INSERT INTO heat_treat_jobs ( card_id, batch ) SELECT atheattreat.id, CInt([Forms]![heat_treat_loads]![batch]) AS Expr1 FROM atheattreat WHERE (((atheattreat.index)=[Forms]![heat_treat_loads]![atheattreat subform].[Form]![index]));